# Disable mouse using a key

Tags: autohotkey, remapping

Is there a way I can assign a key to block other keys using autohotkey?
I've tried this, tried adding parentheses nothing works

Here is the code

```
g::

lbutton::
rbutton::
BlockInput, MouseMove

return
```

as you can see, i want to block mouse input if i pressed g
can anyone help me solve this problem please?

- I've been looking for a solution for 2 hours before posting this so please don't report as repeated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$g::
Mouse_Blocked := true   ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
BlockInput, MouseMove   ; disable MouseMove
return

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys

#If (Mouse_Blocked) ; If this variable has the value "true" 

    ; block mouse input:
    LButton::
    RButton::
    WheelUp::
    WheelDown::
    return

    $g::    ; press g to re-enable MouseMove and mouse input
    BlockInput, MouseMoveOff
    Mouse_Blocked := false
    return


#If ; turn off context sensitivity
```